# How do I Identify which failing hardware is causing hard crashes/reboots?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, gpu, crash, reboot

Recently, my computer started having hard crashes/ reboots.
When on a medium load, the computer appears to randomly reboot, shutting down to BIOS  and just rebooting itself some seconds after.

The first thing I thought about, was a temperature issue, but monitoring temperatures around these reboots showed they never get too high, CPU is around 70°C and so is GPU.

I have a dual boot system, and the problem happens both on Windows 11 and Ubuntu. It leaves no trace in any of the two OSes' logs, neither in the event registry in Windows (aside for a Kernel Power notice) or in kern.log in Ubuntu. It's very much like someone just pulls the power chord and the computer shuts down without logging any reason.

I also can not find a reliable way to reproduce the problem: running stress tests, programs deliberately heavy made with Python, RAM testers or GPU-heavy application like ML or games leads to no result.

Sometimes it runs for hours straight, sometimes it crashes at the slight heavy operation required.

I am running out of ideas on HOW to know which hardware of my setup is failing.

I would think about the PSU or the GPU, because they are the older pieces that the computer is built with, but I can't be sure about it and so I am not investing in any new hardware by now.

Setup is:

```
GPU: MSI 1080ti 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3950x
RAM: 32gb 3600mhz
PSU: EVGA Supernova G31000W  Gold
HDD: Samsung 990 pro 2TB
```

What tests could I do to point out what piece of my computer is failing?
If I am suspecting the PSU to be broken, how can I reproduce the issue to be sure about it?

I also asked a similar question on the askubuntu forums, where you can find some of the ubuntu logs:
https://askubuntu.com/q/1469866/959655

Comment: In Windows : (1) Examine the Event Viewer, (2) If you have recent `.dmp` files in `C:\Windows\Minidump`, zip up a few recent ones and post them online for us to analyze, (3) Examine the SMART values of the disk(s) and post them for us (for tool use for example [speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)), (4) Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bBXSf51n

Here is a CrystalDiskInfo output log. The minidump folder was empty.

Comment: And this one is the only "Error" event I can find in the System event viewer  around the moment of the crash, all the rest is just info level. https://pastebin.com/EfQqVhZK

Comment: These two reports seem to be clean from errors.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. How could I know if it's the PSU ?

Comment: MemTest86 will test the memory and also the general functions of the computer.

Comment: Crossposting is not allowed on these sites. Please close one of your posts and keep just one.